# Hybrid iOS app using Mobile SDK - Defer login screen until triggered

Tags: mobile, salesforce-sdk-hybrid, hybrid-local

We have a hybrid app which is prompting the user to login or register when the app is started (it's the standard Community login page on the Salesforce instance).

We don't want to trigger this login screen immediately on launch, we have several other screens we'd like the user to look through before they launch the login/register process.

There exists blogs and documentation on how to accomplish this for Native iOS applications, but I'm looking for details on how to do it for Hybrid app.

Any ideas?

Comment: I did not work with hybrid app, but I have worked with community. And I know that there is an option to use custom login/register VF pages. With this you can use HTML/CSS/JS to display your own information before showing login/register screens

Answer (score 1):

So the hybrid app is just a wrapper for your Salesforce Community?

If that is the case could you not just replace the community login page with your own custom Visualforce SPA that contains all the pages you want them to view before login?

Note, that would also replace the login screen for the desktop experience as well.

Answer (score 0):

A Hybrid App is nothing more than a Native iOS app that kicks off a Viewer into Salesforce (Ok, it's a little more than that).

I know you can add your own screens to the project and you should be able to place them as the application default launch screens, moving the call to launch the SFDC to some button/action on your native screen.

PS: I am not enough of an ObjC expert to tell you exactly where the changes should be made, but I am sure the Obj-C/Swift StackExchange forum folks would know.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Hybrid apps in Salesforce can be built using :

1) Remote Hybrid approach where VF containers are used .In this case I am sure you can throw your own Visualforce page or a SPA to handle this

2) Local Hybrid App approach where pages reside locally and you do not have much control over the login screen .

In this case have you explored a platform feature known as [Login Flows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYes8OLAc-k).It provides you the ability to add flow screens to your authentication process before user is logged In .

The only caveat I see using this approach is flexibility to brand the screens . You may want to dig a bit into the winter 17 to see if the branding can be controlled .